# I'm creating a Pass-trough GPU in Virtual Macine, need to understand what is " dracut "

Tags: networking, nvidia, kernel, virtualbox, virtualization

@Hello , I'm studing to how to create the Pass-trough GPU in the Virtual Machine enviroment on Ubuntu 21.04. Following the steps on it, it tells  to create in `/etc/dracut.conf.d/` the file `vfio.conf` but in Ubuntu I cannot find this folder /etc/`dracut.conf.d`, it's that because I have to install `dracut-network.deb` or in Ubuntu I will do a mess to install this?
In the end, if i need to install `dracut-network.deb` it's safe to install it, because it's deal with Kernel settings. Or I don't need and it's enouph to create the forlder and file in the related position?

Comment: Dracut is typically used on Fedora. Which guide are you using?

Comment: It's for Fedora OS but it's the most complete for me, there is a related Video as well https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BxAaaRDEEw  . What is the equivalent on Ubuntu in this case?

Comment: Initramfs, probably.

Comment: Ok....but where is located the folder system in /etc/....? And `vfio.conf` should be renamed or keep as it is? Even in Arch said initramfs, but not folder dracut.conf.d in Ubuntu : https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PCI_passthrough_via_OVMF#Isolating_the_GPU